# Switching between two texts with a button with fadein & fadeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, fadein, fadeout

Well, lets say I have div1 and div2, each with different text content.
I want to have a button switch between these every click fading in and out every time.
Can someone help out? I've only been able to make it switch with a timer, but not with a button.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please go through [ask] and [mcve]. Always add the code you've tried with a live demo if possible.

Answer (score 0):

So you want it to switch between two divs? It'd be nice if I could see some work, but saying that you had two divs the following code would start you off with div one and alternate when a button is clicked

### HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<div id = "div1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sit amet facilisis augue. Integer eu quam ac libero efficitur semper ac in lectus. Quisque iaculis elementum quam, nec fermentum turpis.</div>
<div id = "div2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque erat neque, accumsan sodales pharetra in, vestibulum a dui. Nam egestas gravida libero vitae cursus. Fusce ullamcorper felis ligula, laoreet facilisis.</div>
<button onclick = "switchText()">Switch texts</button>
```

### JavaScript (JQuery)

```
$("#div2").hide()
var currentView = "div1"
function switchText(){
if(currentView=="div1"){currentView="div2";$("#div1").hide();$("#div2").show()}
else{currentView="div1";$("#div2").hide();$("#div1").show()}}
```

You can view a demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Officer1/dmrc47b9/)

P.S. Google is usually useful for these kinds of questions